# Accessing DataTemplate's object in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am pretty newborn in .NET MAUI (or even in .NET or C# at all), and because after two days, I still don't liked XAML so much, I decided to implement my UI in C#. I am stuck with a probably pretty obvious problem, namely I would like to access binding values, in order to conditionally re-render my view based on a property.

I have in my ViewModel an Array of structs, let's say:

```
public struct Foo {
    public string Content;
    public int ContentType;
}
```

Now, I just render the content of the array like this.

```
// Collection View
private readonly CollectionView collectionView = new();

...

this.collectionView.ItemsLayout = LinearItemsLayout.Vertical;
this.collectionView.ItemsSource = this.ViewModel.FooItems;

this.collectionView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
    var view = new FooItemView();
    return view;
});

this.collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Bar.FooItems");
```

And my `FooItemView` looks at this point like this:

```
public class FooItemView : ContentView {

    ...

    public FooItemView() {
        Label contentLabel = new();
        contentLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Content");
        this.Content = contentLabel;
    }
}
```

Depending on `Foo.ContentType` I want to display wither a `Label` or something else, like an `Image`
How do I access in `FooItemsView` the `ContentType` property, so I can do this conditional rendering?
Please note, that `FooItems` will be populated asynchronously in a result of an HTTPS request, or I could suddenly change `Foo`'s `ContentType`, so I would like to detect those changes, and set `FooItemsView.Content` according the changes.

I tried to implement `FooItem`'s `get` and `set` method in `FooItemView` along with creating `FooItemProperty` binding, but somehow, If I try to access it, its always `null`.

How would I do this correctly?

Thanks for everyone, who could lead me into the right direction.

Comment: use `this.BindingContext`

Comment: If I managed to understand correctly, `FooItemView` should have as `BindingContext` a `Foo` object. You could access the `Foo` object within the `FooItemView` with `(this.BindingContext as Foo).ContentType`. Otherwise you could consider using a `BindableLayout` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout) with a `DataTemplateSelector` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datatemplateselector?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Whilst everything done in XAML can also be done in C#, I highly recommend you get into XAML. Because you're avoiding XAML, you're avoiding a world that's designed to make your life a whole lot easier, especially CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply, based on @Miguel 's suggestion, I simply used a `DataTemplateSelector`.

@StephenQuan , yes I use the CommunityToolkit - it really makes things more simple, but unfortunately, I am using the Mac version of VS, and a lot of tools are simply not in there like in the Win version, which makes sometimes makes me difficult to find an error in XAML, the only benefit would be only hot reload feature, but I can live without it - my views are little anyway.

Thank you guys!

Comment: @Mancy'sgrandson I have posted a reply based on my previous comment. If you consider it correct, would be great if you mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the rendered UI based on the value of a property of a class by using a [Bindable Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout) and assigning a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datatemplateselector?view=net-maui-7.0) to its `ItemTemplateSelector` property.